# How to label_binarize Multiclass in a specific class order

Tags: python, list, scikit-learn, binary-data

I have a list of ground truth labels:

```
yTrue = ['class2','classC','class3','class3','classA','classB','class2']
```

and a list of the possible classes (distinct, in custom order):

```
orderedClasses = ['classA','class2','classB','class3','classC']
```

I want to code the list in One-Vs-The-Rest for all possible classes.

Desired output:

```
[[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0]]
```

I tried to use `sklearn.preprocessing.label_binarize` ([doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.label_binarize.html#sklearn.preprocessing.label_binarize)) but the problem is it doesn't maintain my custom order for classes:

```
[[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0]]
```

Looking for an Pythonic and efficient way to get the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass `orderedClasses` as `classes` parameter

```
In [15]: label_binarize(yTrue, orderedClasses)
Out[15]:
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: I am not getting this output for the aforementioned example. I am only getting the output as mentioned in my question. Somehow it is mixing the order. What Python version are you running ? mine is 2.7.8